# Rendering Problems:Binary XML file line #-1: No start tag found

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml, android-theme

Initially I was getting error in `Manifest` file at `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` . I look for the solution and from this solution [Android Studio: Error in Layout Files - Header expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758574/android-studio-error-in-layout-files-header-expected#answer-26693139) , I get rid of that error.

But on the other hand I started getting errors in all my layout preview like this [image]

xml file for the above image is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Process Inbox"
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#964acf"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/inbox_expandable_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading">
    </ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried undo the changes but no success, can anyone guide me the reason or solution for the problem.

here is my **app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'

}
```

Comment: @Looser I have updated the xml

Comment: have you tried to clean the project and close the tab and reopen it?

Comment: @Anjali well I dont know whether cleaning works or closing , but its clear now thnks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205766/android-studio-rendering-error/41918140#41918140) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544129/exception-raised-during-renderingbinary-xml-file-line-1error-inflating-class/41918172#41918172)

Moving the problematic tab between different split views did the trick in a second.