# Can not downgrade the Android API version

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38544376/5050667) answer.

I tried installing the previous versions of Android using

```
android
```

in my `cmd` on Windows, checked the previous versions of Android and pressed the button.

[image]

But even after that, I only get the choice to use the latest version of the Android API.

[image]

Comment: what you are looking at in your screenshot are tools, not the actual api. scroll lower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install one of these (i would recommend 23 ;) )

[image: screenshot of android sdk manager]

Answer (score 0):

Press the "SDK Manager" button on the toolbar, then install Android API 5.1 for example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only installing the build tools is not enough, you need to install the other versions of the SDK, in the folders below the build tools