# Android Studio light theme not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio and I want to start making Android apps, but I have a problem:
When I try to change my app's theme to Material Light / Material.Light I get an error:

```
(Rendering Problems)
Exception raised during rendering:
android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable_Delegate.nCreateTreeFromCopy(JJ)J (Details)
```

Log:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable_Delegate.nCreateTreeFromCopy(JJ)J
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.nCreateTreeFromCopy(VectorDrawable.java)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.access$400(VectorDrawable.java:204)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.createNativeTreeFromCopy(VectorDrawable.java:837)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.<init>(VectorDrawable.java:812)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.mutate(VectorDrawable.java:268)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.onStateChange(VectorDrawable.java:392)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setState(Drawable.java:732)
    at android.widget.ImageView.updateDrawable(ImageView.java:927)
    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:509)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:159)
    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:84)
    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:80)
    at android.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowMenuButton.<init>(ActionMenuPresenter.java:841)
    at android.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.initForMenu(ActionMenuPresenter.java:153)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.addMenuPresenter(MenuBuilder.java:229)
    at android.widget.ActionMenuView.getMenu(ActionMenuView.java:646)
    at android.widget.Toolbar.ensureMenu(Toolbar.java:1026)
    at android.widget.Toolbar.getMenu(Toolbar.java:997)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.FrameworkActionBarWrapper$ToolbarWrapper.getMenuBuilder(FrameworkActionBarWrapper.java:222)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.FrameworkActionBarWrapper.inflateMenus(FrameworkActionBarWrapper.java:127)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.FrameworkActionBarWrapper$ToolbarWrapper.inflateMenus(FrameworkActionBarWrapper.java:199)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.FrameworkActionBar.<init>(FrameworkActionBar.java:85)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createActionBar(Layout.java:242)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:152)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:300)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:519)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

EDIT:
I re-installed Android Studio, made a new project and selected API 23. I finally have no errors. Thank you all.

Comment: Could you please show us your code responsible for the theme?

Comment: In your XML  try changing the preview version to API 23 from 24. That should solve the issue . more information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544129/exception-raised-during-renderingbinary-xml-file-line-1error-inflating-class

Comment: @Sriram that won't work, he's having a CRASH here, not a rendering problem.

Comment: @AbAppletic : My bad. I got a bit carried away when he said, he clicked 'Details' which normally appears in XML. due to rendering issue.

Comment: @Sriram happens to all of us

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed Android Studio, made a new project and selected API 23. I finally have no errors. Thank you all. You saved me...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Intellij idea. Andriod Studio was based on it, but Idea updates as soon as possible and has same features.

Answer (score -1):

---

I had this problem once, when I just started to work with android studio. I think that the fastest way of fixing this, is just reinstalling it.

Also, don't forget to copy your projects.