# Rendering problems when adding radiobuttons

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Can't understand what is wrong.

But it builds the app ok and I can start it.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"/>
    </RadioGroup>


</LinearLayout>
```

How to fix it?

And info from my gradle file:

```
...
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
   ...
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
...
```

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable_Delegate.nCreateTreeFromCopy(JJ)J
>       at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.nCreateTreeFromCopy(VectorDrawable.java)
>       at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.access$400(VectorDrawable.java:204)
>       at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.createNativeTreeFromCopy(VectorDrawable.java:837)
>       at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.(VectorDrawable.java:812)
>       at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.mutate(VectorDrawable.java:268)
>       at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.addChild(DrawableContainer.java:817)
>       at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.addStateSet(StateListDrawable.java:329)
>       at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable$AnimatedStateListState.addStateSet(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:602)
>       at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.parseItem(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:525)
>       at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:453)
>       at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.inflate(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:385)
>       at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
>       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1224)
>       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1197)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:315)
>       at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:681)
>       at android.widget.CompoundButton.(CompoundButton.java:89)
>       at android.widget.RadioButton.(RadioButton.java:63)
>       at android.widget.RadioButton.(RadioButton.java:59)
>       at android.widget.RadioButton.(RadioButton.java:55)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor275.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>       at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:107)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
>       at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:149)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:317)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
>       at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
>       at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:519)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
>       at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>       at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: If you are extending AppCompatActivity and your theme is Theme.AppCompat use <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton/> 
This should solve the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see here:
[exception raised during rendering:Binary XML file line #-1:error inflating class<unknown>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544129/exception-raised-during-renderingbinary-xml-file-line-1error-inflating-class)
Installing SDK 23 via the SDK manager and selecting it for the preview worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"   
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn0"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RadioGroup>
```